# Is there a way to invoke a java code (something like custom maven plugins) in bazel build?

Tags: java, maven, bazel

I made a plugin to run it during compilation of maven modules. But since my org is now moving to bazel -- Do we have a way that we can directly run plugins(mojos)in bazel?

If not, is there a way during bazel build of a java code that we can invoke another java code which has all the project info just like `MavenProject` parameter in mojos?

Comment: What does your plugin do?

Comment: What kind of plugin related to maven modules: `I made a plugin to run it during compilation of maven modules`? I have my doubts that you can execute a mojo in Bazel cause as far as I know it bazel primarily implemented in C/C++?

Comment: In particular, does your plugin modify or generate files?

Comment: It generates file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you might want to try is a `java_plugin`, which is for running annotation processors with `java_binary` and `java_library`:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_plugin

and you specify the plugin with the `plugins` attribute of `java_binary` or `java_library`:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_binary.plugins

```py
java_binary(
  name = ...,
  srcs = ...,
  deps = ...,
  plugins = [":my_plugin"],
)

java_plugin(
  name = "my_plugin",
  srcs = ...,
  deps = ...,
  processor_class = "...",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`genrule`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule) with the `java_binary` for your plugin as a `tool`. Something like this:

```
java_binary(
    name = "my_plugin",
    ...
)

genrule(
    name = "run_plugin",
    srcs = [],
    cmd = "$(location my_plugin) > \"$@\"",
    outs = ["plugin_output"],
    tools = [":my_plugin"],
)
```

In this example, you should be able to run your plugin with `bazel build :plugin_output`.

Comment: I want to get classloader of the module executing it (urlclassloader works too but I need to know the runtime dependencies of the module). Would genrule provide me that?

Comment: This example just executes your plugin with `java -jar` from the genrule, so it will give you whatever `java -jar` ordinarily gives you, I guess.

Comment: Then could you clarify some more? You need the runtime dependencies of what module? The one that your plugin is acting on or the plugin itself? Would knowing the Bazel `deps` suffice? Are you talking about Java 9 modules or some other concept?

Comment: It might help if you could share the purpose of the plugin as well.

Comment: I am using java 8. Basically, I want to get all runtime dependencies use reflection on all the modules and then generate few files based on the classes having annotations.

Comment: [https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator/blob/995b1817ab6c0a7f77438364416d420e53f29432/jsonschema-maven-plugin/src/main/java/com/github/victools/jsonschema/plugin/maven/SchemaGeneratorMojo.java#L408]
This can act as a reference.